# Pre-save hook and instance methods in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sequelize.js

Are there pre-save hooks and instance methods in [Sequelize.js?](http://sequelizejs.com)

Specifically I need to convert this Mongoose code into an equivalent Sequelize code:

### Schema

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
  token: String
});
```

### Pre-save

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var user = this;

  var hashContent = user.username + user.password + Date.now() + Math.random();
  user.token = crypto.createHash('sha1').update(hashContent).digest('hex');

  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
  bcrypt.genSalt(5, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

### Instance method

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if(err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is to expand your model with class or instance methods:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    username: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true },
    email: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true },
    password: Sequelize.STRING,
    token: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    instanceMethods: {
        comparePassword : function(candidatePassword, cb) {
            bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.getDataValue('password'), function(err, isMatch) {
                if(err) return cb(err);
                cb(null, isMatch);
            });
        },
        setToken: function(){
            // bla bla bla
            // bla bla bla
        },
        getFullname: function() {
            return [this.firstname, this.lastname].join(' ');
        }
    }
})
```

So when you do

```
User.build({ firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar' }).getFullname(); // 'foo bar'
```

So, to set the token, you can do it like this:

```
User.build({ ... }).setToken().save();
```

Or, to use the comparePassword function:

```
User.find({ ... }).success(function(user) { user.comparePassword('the password to check', function(err, isMatch) { ... } });
```

You can see this in the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#expansion-of-models)

**Edit**

On recent versions of there are hooks for each model, you can check the [hooks documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/hooks.html) which are very pretty straightforward and complement them with the class or instance methods.

Comment: The "pre-save" method in the question sets not only user.token but also user.password. Is setToken (in the sequelize version presented in this answer) meant to replace the "pre-save" method presented in the question, and if so, isn't a more appropriate name setTokenAndPass?

Comment: Also, when I call the instance method on the object returned by build, I get the following error:  built_obj.setPass is not a function (where setPass is my instance method). Any tips?

Comment: already added an edit for hooks which are available now as part of Sequelize @GobiDasu, no idea why you get that errors but won't be able to help without any visible code. Regards

Answer (score 8):

I faced same issue, but atleast in 2.0 version of sequelize this feature is available, the complete documentation is available at [Hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/).

Below is a sample code that uses a **beforeValidate** hook:

```
"use strict";
var md5 = require('blueimp-md5').md5;

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Sms = sequelize.define("sms", {
    senderName: DataTypes.STRING,
    smsBody : {
      type : DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false
    },
    userId : {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull:false
    },
    hash : {
      type:DataTypes.CHAR(32),
      unique:true,
      allowNull:false
    }

  });

Sms.beforeValidate(function(sms){
  sms.hash = md5(sms.smsBody+sms.userId);
  return sequelize.Promise.resolve(sms)
});


return Sms;
};
```

The requirement here was, create a hash using smsBody and userId, so i created hook i.e. **beforeValidate**, this hook will be executed before any validations are performed by Sequelize on the model. There are many other hooks available and best part is you don't have to write any additional code while you save your data, these hooks will take care of that.

You should choose wisely between hooks and instanceMethods. But in your case i guess hooks would be a better choice

Comment: Note: md5 is not the way to do password hashing, you should use a hashing alghorithm which isn't broken and is more expensive to hash with to make it more difficult for attackers to crack. A system such as bcrypt or pbkdf2.

Comment: @leroydev totally agree.. here i just used md5 as an example and if you look carefully, the example that i gave is not storing the password. Its creating a hash from content that is used to maintain uniqueness. So i guess for this scenario its fine.

But surely for storing passwords, this approach is horrible that.

Comment: I know this is not for saving passwords, but the question was about saving passwords, that's why I added the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for in sequilize world is beforeCreate hook. It would go something like this:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
 const User = sequelize.define('users', {    
   username: { type: String, unique: true },
   email: { type: String, unique: true },
      password: String,
      token: String
    },
    {
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: function(user){
         
         // do your hashing here to user.password
      }
    }
});
```