# How to auto populate the Many-To-Many third table through table in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, relational-database, associations

I am new to Sequelize I have a Postgres Database

I have two table that needs to be in relation to each other as Many-to-Many relation based on a through table.

The first two tables are:

1. customer
2. store_products

And the third table that is in between them is order_list:

And here is how I established their connection with the order_list table:

```
  Customer.associate = models => {
    Customer.belongsToMany(models.StoreProduct, { 
      through: models.OrderList,
      unique: false,
      foreignKey: 'customers_cid',
    });
  }
 
// and for the StoreProduct I have it like this

  StoreProduct.associate = models => {
    StoreProduct.belongsToMany(models.Customer, { 
      through: models.OrderList,
      unique: false,
      foreignKey: 'store_products_spid',
    });
  }
```

Then as for the OrderList Table I wanted to include two additional columns quantity and price.

The quantity will basically be customer picking a number of store_product items. Then I wanted the price column to record the number of items the customer picked as quantity * the price of the cost of the product. I have a price column in `store_products` `table` as so I wanted the `quantity` recorded on `order_list table` * `price` from the `store_products table` basically. Cant figure out how to do this inside the `order_list table` `price` column.

here is my defined `order_list table`

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const OrderList = sequelize.define('OrderList', {
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    price: { // Here I wanted SUM(quantity * StoreProductID.price) How do I do it?
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2)
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'order_list',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    // paranoid: true
  });

  return OrderList;
}
```

Here is the rest of defined two tables StoreProduct

```
  const StoreProduct = sequelize.define('StoreProduct', {
    spid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    product_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      // validate: {
      //   len: [1, 100]
      // }
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
      allowNull: true,
    //   validate: {
    //     len: [1, 100]
    //   }
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2),
      allowNull: false
    },
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'store_products',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    // freezeTableName: true
    // paranoid: true
  })
```

Customer Table

```
  const Customer = sequelize.define('Customer', {
    cid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
    },
    last_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
    },
    address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false
    }, 
    zip_code: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(25),
      allowNull: false      
    },
    city: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
    country: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'customers',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    // paranoid: true
  })
```

So I wanted the `price` column from the `order_list table` to monitor this SQL query basically but done in the world of Sequelize which I am new too:

```
SELECT SUM(StoreProduct.price * OrderList.quantity) 
FROM store_products AS StoreProduct
JOIN order_list AS OrderList
ON OrderList.store_products_spid = StoreProduct.spid;
```

// or maybe remove SUM idk but non the less

I want

StoreProduct.price * OrderList.quantity

Done inside the define in the `price` column of `order_list table`

```
  const OrderList = sequelize.define('OrderList', {
    quantity: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    price: { // DONE HERE StoreProduct.price * OrderList.quantity with StoreProduct the FKEY as demonstrated above
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10, 2)
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'order_list',
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    // paranoid: true
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the price when entering the order data you can fetch the product and while adding the entery you can multiply the product price with the quantity.
Or you could create a "pre-save" method that does it automaticly everytime a new entery is created [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21411848/pre-save-hook-and-instance-methods-in-sequelize/30726876)